# How to modify elements at a specific index in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem modifying elements in an array list at a specific index. Please help me how to do that. Thank you.

This is my Arraylist of type List(class). How to modify values in the arraylist at a specific index

```
ArrayList<List> al = new ArrayList<List>();
```

This is my list  class

```
 public class List{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What has java.util.List to do with your List class? Its confusing. If you just want to add/delete an element at an Index in ArrayList use, al.add(index,Object), e.g al.add(1, "Hello)

Comment: You have *what* problem?

Comment: `al.get(i).setX(x)`....?

Comment: Your question is unclear and attracts guess work and conjecture. Do you want to change the instance of the object at the given index or do you want to change the properties of the object at the given index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by getting a reference of the object at the given index...

```
int index = ...; // Index of value to be modified...
List value = al.get(index);
```

Then modify the properties of the object...

```
value.setX(x);
value.setY(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

al.set(index, new_value);

Easy ;)

Comment: hello thq for your response. but arraylist is of type class. it has two values x and y to be modified. How to modify both the the values at that index

Comment: @user3857268 You you don't want to modify the value at the given index but the properties of the value at the given index?

Comment: `al.get(index).setX(new_value);`

Or `al.get(index).setY(new_value);`, depending on the value you want to modify.

Comment: @user3857268 no my mate, this answer is correct, try it.

Comment: @NonExistent Not according to the requirements of the OP, they don't want to change the object reference at the given index, but modify the properties of the object at the given index...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, well the question was a bit unclear.

Comment: @NonExistent That we can agree on ;)